# How to export huge data from sql server into excel file

Tags: sql-server, excel, ms-access, ssms, export-to-excel

I want to export huge data(about 5 millions rows with 2 columns) from sql server management studio into excel file, but the maximum size of excel file is around 1400000 rows

i tried import and export wizard but it does not work perfectly 
it returns 60000 records then the error occur:

[image]

when i choose the destination file, i should use one of excel versions
if i choose 'Microsoft Excel 2007' the message appear(the 'Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0' provider is not registered on the local machine.(System.Date)) so i chose 'Microsoft excel 97-2003'

i want to export data to excel or access.

any suggestion?

Comment: What are you planning to do with the data? It is probably better to open Excel and import the data into a pivot table and summarize from there. This allows a lot more than a million rows of data.

Comment: "I want to export 5M records to Excel, but Excel's maximum is 1M rows, what can I do?". Well, not a lot, if you exceed the maximum there is very little we can do for you.

Comment: Let's see, "I want to pour a full pint of milk into a half pint pot".... Yeah, nothing wrong with that!

Comment: Access doesn't not have the 1M row limitation. Have you installed Access on the machine running the SSIS package? See https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/f11b2df9-fd0a-4528-987f-f95dfdccee0a/microsoftaceoledb120-provider-is-not-registered-on-the-local-machine-error

Comment: If you happen to have Excel 2010+ then you also might use the direction connection to SQL Server, with PowerPivot/PowerQuery. If so, Excel may exceed this limit. One caveat: Excel does then not store the data, it only loads it every time you open Excel. That also means that you need enough RAM available for this amount of data.

Comment: @jkpieterse I tried Pivot Table, but it does not work. when i click on the desired column, the next message appear"A field in your source data has more unique items than can be used in a PivotTable.
Microsoft Excel may not be able to create the report, or may create the report without the data from this field."

Comment: Sounds like you have a file in xls format. Trys this in a file with xlsx fileformat.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"i want to export data to excel or access."

Therefore import it to Access. 2007 has an overall 2GB Table size limitation, but no row limitation (that I can remember).

Excel ain't gonna work for you. 2003 (and other's when running in 2003 compatability mode) have a limitation of 65,535 rows, 2007+ 1,048,576 rows.